# How to exclude "Process Monitor" from Themida's list of monitoring programs

Tags: debugging, decompilation, memory, driver, processhacker

Can Themida be made to whitelist a particular program of its list of "monitoring programs", whether through reversing or compile-flags?

I want to exclude Sysinternals "Process Monitor" from the list, particularly since Process Monitor loads a filter driver upon running which does not have an unload function, requiring a full system reboot for it to unload, and thus Themida stop complaining.

[image: Themida complaint of monitoring programs]